# Application Event Not fetching Data

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using an applicationEvent in an lightning component

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Payment Information">
  <aura:attribute name="paymentInfoData" type="Object[]" description="Store the paymentInfo Data"/>
</aura:event>
```

Then in componentA I am registering the event

```
<aura:registerEvent name="PaymentInformation" type="c:GPS_EVNT_PaymentInformation"/>
```

Then in controller I am doing as below

```
var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:GPS_EVNT_PaymentInformation");
appEvent.setParams({
    "paymentInfoData": 'Hello Friends'
})
appEvent.fire();
In componentB I am handling the event


 <aura: handler event = "c:GPS_EVNT_PaymentInformation"
action = "{!c.handlePaymentInformation}" / >
    handlePaymentInformation: function(component, event, helper) {
        if (event.getParam("paymentInfoData"))
            var paymentRecords = event.getParam("paymentInfoData");
        console.log('paymentRecords =', paymentRecords);
    }
```

I am not able to retrieve the data in component B after the application event is handled. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you have the same name on aura:registerEvent and the listener component, if you use different names then you cannot listen to platform events.
Also a good tool available on Chrome to inspect Salesforce Events is Lightning inspector (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lightning-insp/pcpmcffcomlcjgpcheokdfcjipanjdpc?hl=en-US). This tool captures both component and lightning events.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I resolved my issue, thanks